# C# async and tasks

Tags: c#

I have a function that sends requests to search for information from a url. The search criteria is a list and the search iterates through each item and requests info from the url. To speed it up I divide the list into x subsets, and create a task for each subset. Then each subset sends 3 simultaneous requests, as follows:

This is the main entry point:

```
Search search = new Search();
await Task.Run(() => search.Start());
```

The Start function:

```
public void Search()
{
    //Each subset is a List<T> ie where T is certain search criteria
    //If originalList.Count = 30 and max items per subset is 10, then subsets will be 3 lists of 10 items each
    var subsets = CreateSubsets(originalList);

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(subsets.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < subsets.Count; i++)
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SearchSubset(subsets[i]));

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    foreach (Task task in tasks)
        if (task != null)
            task.Dispose();
}

private void SearchSubset(List<SearchCriteria> subset)
{
    //Checking that i+1 and i+2 is within subset.Count-1 has been omitted
    for (int i = 0; i < subset.Count; i+=3)
    {
        Task[] tasks = {Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SearchCriteria(subset[i])), 
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SearchCriteria(subset[i+1])),
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SearchCriteria(subset[i+2]))};

        //Wait & dispose like above
    } 
}

private void SearchCriteria(SearchCriteria criteria)
{
    //SearchForCriteria uses WebRequest and WebResponse (callback)
    //to query the url and return the response.content

    var results = SearchForCriteria(criteria);

    //process results...
}
```

The above code works fine and the search is quite fast. However, does the above code create too much overhead, and is there is more cleaner (or simpler) way to achieve the same results?

Comment: You don't need to dispose of tasks, which could make your code simpler.

Comment: Looks to me like you could/should be using the TPL to do the search.  The partitioning and scheduling you're doing will all be handled for you.

Comment: How will the code above look like if it has to bee changed to use TPL?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient method, but if this is for a desktop application, efficiency isn't your primary concern anyway. So, unless you are actually seeing performance degradation from this code, you shouldn't change it.

That said, I would have approached this differently.

You're using the TPL to parallelize I/O-bound operations. You're using [dynamic parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx), the most complex kind; as Jeff Mercado commented, your code would be simpler and slightly more efficient if you used a higher-level parallelism abstraction such as [`Parallel` or `PLINQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx)).

However, any *parallel* approach is going to waste thread pool threads by blocking them. Since this is I/O-bound, I would recommend using `async`/`await` to make them concurrent.

If you want to do simple throttling, you can use `SemaphoreSlim`. I don't think you need to do throttling like this in addition to your subsets, but if you want an `async` equivalent to your existing code, it would look something like this:

```
public Task SearchAsync()
{
  var subsets = CreateSubsets(originalList);
 return Task.WhenAll(subsets.Select(subset => SearchSubsetAsync(subset)));
}

private Task SearchSubsetAsync(List<SearchCriteria> subset)
{
  var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(3);
  return Task.WhenAll(subset.Select(criteria => SearchCriteriaAsync(criteria, semaphore)));
}

private async Task SearchCriteriaAsync(SearchCriteria criteria, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
  await semaphore.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    // SearchForCriteriaAsync uses HttpClient (async).
    var results = await SearchForCriteriaAsync(criteria);

    // Consider returning results rather than processing them here.
  }
  finally
  {
    semaphore.Release();
  }
}
```